# Entity Framework: how can I initialize a column value to GetUtcDate()?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework (previously I created a database in SSMS and then accessed it with ADO.NET).

When I did it that way, for numerous tables I had a column named `Created` that was assigned a default value of `GetUtcDate()`. And then for any inserts/updates that column value was not set thereby retaining it's original value.

Is there a way to do this in Entity Framework? I know I can set the value in the constructor and write it that way but I prefer having SQL Server do it directly.

And is there a way for that column to be read-only after a row is created? If I only have {get;} for that property, then EF can't initialize it when reading the row - correct?

Comment: Did [Generated Values > Default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#default-values) in the Entity Framework documentation shed any light on the subject?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes! thank you. In fact their second example is my exact case. If you write this as an answer, happy to accept it.